# Concat two Pandas dataframes without sorting on initial columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames:

Dataframe A

```
index  ID_1  ID_2   Value
0       1     1      1.0
1       1     2      1.2
2       1     3      1.3
```

DataFrame B

```
index  ID_1  ID_2   Value
0       1     2      1.0
1       1     1      1.2
2       1     3      1.3
```

And each is sorted by ID_1, then by Value.

I want to merge or concatenate the two dataframes so that I can easily determine where ID_2 in dataframe A and dataframe B are not the same - so determine when the sorting I have highlights a difference in the order of the ID_2 column.

I have tried to use pd.concat several different ways and I always get this result:

```
index  ID_1  ID_2   Value    ID_1  ID_2   Value
0       1     1      1.0      1     1      1.2
1       1     2      1.2      1     2      1.0
2       1     3      1.3      1     3      1.3
```

Rather than what I want:

```
index  ID_1  ID_2   Value    ID_1  ID_2   Value
0       1     1      1.0      1     2      1.0
1       1     2      1.2      1     1      1.2
2       1     3      1.3      1     3      1.3
```

Any ideas?  I have tried it with different column names, etc.

Edit:

The solution proposed below of course works, but one must remember to do `reset_index(drop=True)` on the dataframe to have the indexes reset after the sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works for me
assuming `'index'` is the index for both `A` and `B`

```
pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's that I'm assuming the sort I did reindexed things, and it probably didn't.

Comment: @traggatmot it certainly did not.  use `reset_index(drop=True)` to accomplish that.